# Best definition of analytic geometry

Tags: terminology, definition

I found a few different definitions online, none of which I found to be perfect, which I combined into "the representation of geometric objects and their positions and properties using coordinate systems and algebraic equations".  Does anyone who's studied the subject have a better definition or a formal definition that isn't too complicated?

Comment: Your definition sounds good. Maybe: “An approach to geometry that uses coordinate systems and algebraic equations to describe geometric objects. For example, once a Cartesian coordinate system has been introduced for a given plane, the set of all points in the plane whose coordinates $(x,y)$ satisfy $x^2 + y^2=1$ is a circle of radius $1$ centered at the origin.”

Answer (score 1):

Branches of mathematics do not have "formal definitions", they are defined by how people refer to them.

Your definition sounds fine.

I like to think of this historically: before Descartes we had "synthetic" geometry, i.e. axiomatic geometry in the style of Euclid; after Descartes we could model Euclid's geometry using numeric axes and that was the birth of "analytic" geometry.